# Каким образом лучше организовать отношения классов?

Tags: ооп

Есть виртуальный класс Vehicle, от него наследуются TruckVehicle и PassengerVehicle, каждый из объектов этих классов должен иметь 1 объект класса Persons и 1 объект класса Driver. (Для этого, наверное, стоит использовать включение?)

Класс Road может иметь **несколько** объектов классов TruckVehicle и PassengerVehicle.

Comment: Ну вот так, как вы описали, так и делайте. В чём вы видите проблему?

Comment: (Только не сделайте класс Vehicle ответственным за время жизни водителя, водитель имеет право жить и после утилизации машины.)

Comment: @VladD это зависит от политического режима

Comment: @VladD у Road несколько объектов, и я не знаю изначально сколько. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Etki: Ну, при роботизме-бендеризме водителя, конечно, пустят на запчасти :)

Comment: @Olfy: Ну заведите у `Road` список машин, находящихся в данный момент на ней.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте отдельный класс *VenicleCollection* - коллекцию объектов типа Venicle, определите методы добавления/удаления элементов из коллекции, перебора элементов в ней и пр. И вот уже экземпляр этого класса пусть в себе композиционно содержит объект класса **Road**.